# Is learning jQuery for DOM manipulation necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

From what I can tell, jQuery was popularised when IE6 and Netscape were popular and the DOM document object was nonexistent. Nowadays, it seems relatively easy to just use document.querySelector() to bypass the need for jQuery. It's even been shown to be more performant to use native javascript over jQuery for DOM manipulation.

If we can just use the document object to perform all DOM manipulations we want, and jQuery have been shown to be less performant, then even if we can use jQuery, isn't it advisable to do DOM manipulations natively for performance anyway? So, my question is, is learning jQuery still necessary nowadays?

Comment: There are two opinions on this. a: yes. b: no

Comment: So the question is opinion based.

Comment: Given that jQuery **is** JavaScript, the answer is, obviously, "No, it's not *necessary*." Beyond that, this question is way too broad and opinion based. The question quickly devolves into "is it a good idea"/"is it beneficial", which is, at best, opinion based. Without more detail as to the requirements, it's not even possible to provide more than overly broad, general opinions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still applying for a job and if the required skills don't say Jquery then no need to learn. Also if you already know Javascript and in case you really need to use Jquery then it won't be hard for you to learn it since it's just a lightweight JS library.

Comment: jQuery is a blasted, slow library. It's everything but lightweight